# Getting the following error - No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost: 5432/testDBMS

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I get back an error indicating java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
    jdbc:postgresql://localhost:
    5432/testDBMS

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JdbcPostgresqlConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn3 = null;

    try {
        String dbURL3 = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testDBMS";
        Properties parameters = new Properties();
            parameters.put("user", "pgmrHere");
            parameters.put("password", "111111");
        conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL3, parameters);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the PostgreSQL JDBC driver on your classpath?

Comment: JAVA VERSION is jdk1.7.0_45, PostgreSQL is 9.3 Build 1102, - IN THE JAVA BIN, JAVA LIB, AND POSTGRESQL LIB FOLDERS are postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar andpostgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar, - ALL JAR FOLDERS ARE IN CLASSPATH, THE ERROR IS - C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp . JdbcPostgresqlConnection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost: 5432/testDBMS

Comment: the jar files ARE IN MY CLASSPATH - C:\Documents and Settings\ckemp>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\P
rogram Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib

Comment: No, they aren't. Because you're using the `-cp` option of java, which **sets** the classpath of the program to the value of the `-cp` option, and thus ignores the CLASSPATH environment variable. Never use the global CLASSPATH. Always pass an explicit classpath with `-cp`. BTW, even if you didn't use -cp, they wouldn't be in the classpath. Look at your classpath: does it contain a .jar file? No it doesn't. All it contains is directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
java -cp . JdbcPostgresqlConnection
```

So, clearly, the only thing that is in the classpath is the current directory (`.`). The postgresql driver jar is not. You need to add it to the classpath:

```
java -cp .:/path/to/driver.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection
```

on Linux/MacOS, or

```
java -cp .;c:\path\to\driver.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection
```

on Windows.

Comment: the results of your suggestion - C:\AZ_Fantasy5>

java -cp .;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-110
2.jdbc4.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3
-1102.jdbc4.jar

Comment: classpath is in the environment table and verified by %CLASSPATH% command

Comment: Read my comment at the bottom of your question. Avoid putting jars in directories containing a space character. Or surround the path containing space characters with double quotes.

Comment: jar folder - C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib

Comment: Yes so what? Don't you see it contains a white space between "Program" and "Files"? Surround the path of the jar by double quotes: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar"`, as I just told you.

Comment: C:\AZ_Fantasy5>cd \AZ_Fantasy5

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>javac JdbcPostgresqlConnection.java

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp .;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-110
2.jdbc4.jar C:\AZ_Fantasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3
-1102.jdbc4.jar

Comment: moved the jar files to the folder of the java program (no spaces in name) with this result - C:\AZ_Fantasy5>cd \AZ_Fantasy5

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>javac JdbcPostgresqlConnection.java

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp .;C:\AZ_Fantasy5\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar C:\AZ_Fan
tasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\AZ_Fantasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll stop answering if you don't read what I say. I told you twice to surround the path by double quotes. I even did it for you. And your command still doesn't contain any double quote.  You just have to copy and paste. Is it really so hard? Here's the complete command. Copy and paste it: `java -cp.;"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar" JdbcPostgresqlConnection`.

Comment: commenting out the database code, and the 'could not find or load main class' error goes away.

Comment: java takes a class name as argument. Not the path of a .class file. Read my answer again. The class name is `JdbcPostgresqlConnection`. Not `C:\AZ_Fantasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection`.

Comment: with the quotes - C:\AZ_Fantasy5>cd \AZ_Fantasy5

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>javac JdbcPostgresqlConnection.java

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-11
02.jdbc4.jar" C:\AZ_Fantasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\AZ_Fantasy5\JdbcPostgresqlConnection

Comment: Read what I just told you. Read it again. And again. Copy and paste the command I gave you.

Comment: C:\AZ_Fantasy5>cd \AZ_Fantasy5

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>javac JdbcPostgresqlConnection.java

C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-11
02.jdbc4.jar" JdbcPostgresqlConnection
Connected to database #3

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to compile was - java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar" JdbcPostgresqlConnection. Note 2 things; the quotes around the jar specification and the jar files cannot be in a folder with a space in the name. This is normally not the case on *nix system, but is often encountered in Windows systems. Note too, that when I put the jar file in the same folder with the java program I could eliminate the double quotes - java -cp .;C:\AZ_Fantasy5\postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection. Special thanks to JB Nizet for pointing out this situation.

Comment: Oh my. They **can** be under a path containing a space. BTW, your example shows that they are. The windows command prompt simply expects such space-containing paths to be surrounded by double quotes, since a space normally ends an argument and starts a new one. Why do you answer your own question instead of accepting the correct ones from people who have spent time helping you?

Answer (score 0):

```
As the error says java -cp . JdbcPostgresqlConnection java.sql.SQLException: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost: 5432/testDBMS
```

Which means you didnot include the postgresql.jar in your classpath

Try executing like this and I'm assuming it is Windows OS by seeing your error

```
java -cp .;pathOfYourDriverjar/postgresql.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection
```

Comment: results of your suggestion - C:\AZ_Fantasy5>
C:\AZ_Fantasy5>java -cp .;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3-110
2.jdbc4.jar JdbcPostgresqlConnection
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\lib\postgresql-9.3
-1102.jdbc4.jar

Answer (score 0):

Did you not load the driver in your code? Either define the `jdbc.drivers` property setting it to `org.postgresql.Driver` or add `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` to your code.

Comment: my error in copying the code over. Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") is in the code. Error remains.

Comment: @CaseyKemp the code you posted has no mention of the line I've suggested you add